# Dotnet ef command isn't working, installed but not showing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, command-line-interface

I'm working on a project and it involves entity framework. I was able to work with EF before, something happened, but the dotnet-ef command isn't working anymore.

installing it again, with

```
dotnet install tool --global dotnet-ef
dotnet install tool --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
```

uninstalling, and installing components, visual studio itself
adding path variables, like `users\%user%\.dotnet\tools`.

[image: CLI commands also tried]

[image: the PROBLEM]

Comment: Please define "is isn't working": what symptoms to you see?

Comment: when i try to execute the 'dotnet-ef' command.

Comment: Yes, but when you execute it what happens? Do you get an error? Or something else? (Please add to the question: don;t use a comment.)

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's at the bottom of the post under PROBLEM

Comment: have you tried adding it to the PATH as suggested by the console message?

Comment: i didn't know what the right path variable was, because i tested the commands in each map under user\dotnet\tools, but i just found the right path, thanks anyway.

the solution i was seeking: add path variable 
users\%user%\.dotnet\tools